# Proper regex for strings for starting and ending with number

Tags: regex

I know it is maybe a simple question but i couldn't find the correction of my regex after an hour so i decided to ask it.

What I'm trying is :

```
^[0-9]{14}.*?_[0-9]{13}$
```

for the strings

```
58300000164329_1422947665835
58300000168754_ARA_DE_A_1422947398449
Customer_information_Refrigeration_Transition_1421678259290
58300000157376_ara_es_d_1421678030359
20120612_6_1421677861200
```

The main thing is starting with 14 numbers and ending with '_' and 13 numbers. Where is the problem in my regex ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Which of these strings are invalid? Your regex does not match `Customer_information_Refrigeration_Transition_1421678259290` and `20120612_6_1421677861200`, do you want to match them? See https://regex101.com/r/iJ6dJ7/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, you need to add 2 `_`. One that will be always there and other one is optional.

Use this updated RegEx:

```
\b([0-9]{14}_)?.*_?[0-9]{13}\b
```

[RegEx Demo & Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/hF7zC4/2)

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, use this RegEx: `.*_[0-9]{13}\b`

[Demo & Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/hF7zC4/4)

Comment: .*_?[0-9]{13}\b is the main answer i guess because of the string "Customer_information_Refrigeration_Transition_1421678259290", many thanks for your correction!

Comment: @Hayra This one is more correct: `.*_[0-9]{13}\b` Note that there will always be a `_` before the numbers, so no need of `?` for that in regex.